# How do I copy a Magento sub-store on the same server

Tags: magento

I have a Magento store running with sub-stores as add-on domains. (Example: magentostore.com and hats.com) I wish to make a copy of one of the sub-stores to a new sub-store so that we can modify it. Example, copy hats.com to boots.com, and then modify boots.com while leaving hats.com alone. This new store will be on the same server. I do NOT want to move it to another store; I want it to exist as a new sub-store.

I have already: Created an apache virtual host pointing to a new directory (Sites/hats.com). I have created the symlinks in said sub-directory to point to 'app', 'var', 'media', and the other directories as required for an add-on domain sub-store. And I have modified the index.php with the name of the new sub-store.

My question is how do I make a copy from an existing store, into a new store so that we have a starting point to modify from.

I have full access to the server, and can perform SQL queries if that is the solution. I can copy files, or access the Magento Admin interface. I just don't see how to copy a store, except to a new location.

Comment: Interesting question. This should be doable, just needs to be exhaustive. Need to understand how each relevant table plays in and duplicate the data. Unless you can find a ready made version, this may take some time to work up.